# Unable to mount NFS share to one of the blades on my ESX Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage, vmware-esx

I'm getting the following error when trying to mount an NFS share to one of my blades on ESX:

"Error during the configuration of the host: NFS Error: Unable to Mount filesystem: Unable to connect to NFS server"

There are 3 other blades setup exactly the same which are not having this issue. I have unmounted the NFS share from the other blades to be sure that this isn't an issue having to do with exceeding the maximum number of connections on that NFS share.

This is an HP Blade Server and the NFS share is setup on an HP server running Storage Server 2003 R2.

Does anybody have any idea as to what might be going on? The logs I've looked at haven't said much besides the fact that it is unable to connect to the NFS share. I'm able to ping the server hosting the NFS share without issue and the root Unix user is mapped to the backup user and everything is setup properly as far as that goes (as can be witnessed by the fact that the other 3 blades are able to mount the NFS share without a problem).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: vmkping did not work when trying to ping the server hosting the NFS share from the blade...I'm going to try and blow out the vmkernel and set it back up to see if this resolves the issue. Any recommendations would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doublecheck the logs, both on the client-side and on the server-side.  Turn up verbosity on the logging, if that's an available option.

If that doesn't work, I'd fire up `Wireshark` or `tcpdump` and take a look at the actual network traffic.  Given a choice, I usually like to watch from the server-side, but you can still learn a lot from the client-side.  This can help tell you whether the traffic actually getting through, whether it's being responded to, rejected, etc.

Reading packet captures isn't necessarily the easiest thing to do, if you've never done it before, but that's where I usually turn when I'm troubleshooting connectivity problems and the logs don't help.